# How can I convert a Hedera Account ID Alias (hexadecimal) into a Hedera Account ID Alias (chacracters only)?

Tags: javascript, sdk, hedera-hashgraph

I am wondering how I can convert an Account ID alias (hexadecimal) into an Account ID alias (characters only). For example, from the format `0.0.302a300506032b657003210030a028ee7fd716c438de818a8831ed2235d0f85e430ab036dbfac173eb50aef9` to the format `0.0.HIQQEXWKW53RKN4W6XXC4Q232SYNZ3SZANVZZSUME5B5PRGXL663UAQA.` Is there any function in the Hedera SDK that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can retrieve this information using a Mirror Node API request:
​

```js
    const accountInfoFetchUrl = `https://testnet.mirrornode.hedera.com/api/v1/accounts?account.publickey=${publicKey}&balance=false&limit=1&order=desc`;
    const accountInfoResponse = await fetch(accountInfoFetchUrl);
    const accountInfo = (await accountInfo.json).accounts[0];
```

​
The public key is passed in using the `account.publickey` query parameter.

The `accountInfo` objects contain the field that you are looking for (and several others).

---

​
***Additional info***
​

The "very long account ID" is actually a "long account ID",
which is defined in [HIP-32 - Auto Account Creation](https://hips.hedera.com/hip/hip-32).

Note that this **should not** be confused with any of the acount alias formats defined in
[HIP-583 - Expand alias support in CryptoCreate & CryptoTransfer Transactions](https://hips.hedera.com/hip/hip-583).

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this, without invoking the Mirror Node APIs,
is to perform the required [IETF RFC 4648](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4648#section-6) `base32url` conversion locally.
To do this, you will need the `rfc4648` npm package.
This process is described in [HIP-32](https://hips.hedera.com/hip/hip-32).

```
const publicKeyRawStr = publicKey.toStringRaw();
const protoBufPrefix = `1220`;
const bufferRaw = Buffer.from(`${protoBufPrefix}${publicKeyRawStr}`, 'hex');
const longAccountId = base32.stringify(bufferRaw, { pad: false });

console.log(`publicKeyRawStr: ${publicKeyRawStr}`);
console.log(`longAccountId: ${longAccountId}`);
```